# Probability of running out of cards in draw poker

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Seven players sit down for a hand of draw poker.  If a player has a one-pair hand, she will call the first-round bets, thus participating in the draw; and all players drawing to one pair will want to draw three cards.

Thus if six or more players are originally dealt one-pair, the stack of careds available for drawing will run out.

**What is the probability of six or more players, out of seven, each having one pair?**

And how does that probability compare to $p^7+7p^6(1-p)$ where $p$ is the probability of a five-card freshly dealt hand being one-pair?  (It must be somewhat greater, but by what factor?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can determine the probability $p_k$ for all of $k$ people being dealt a one-pair hand, then the desired probability is $7p_6-6p_7$.

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/02897b5d33ed7c78e61c923fbe741525) that computes the probability $p_k$ by successively choosing ranks for the one-pair hands of the players, keeping track of the depletion of the ranks and memoising the results. The complexity is determined by the number of different depletion patterns, which is $\binom{13+4}4=2380$, so this is not a big computation.

The results are:

\begin{align}
p_6=\frac{12459207197065420800}{2102041714430930451179}&\approx0.00592719\;,\\
p_7=\frac{2711631680942502666240}{1066936315910442270434141}&\approx0.00254151\;,\\
p_{\ge6}=7p_6-6p_7=\frac{27997773085518424104960}{1066936315910442270434141}&\approx0.02624128\;.
\end{align}

The probability $p=p_1$ of one player being dealt a one-pair hand is $\frac{352}{833}\approx0.42256903$, so the probability you wanted to compare to is

$$
p_1^7+7p_1^6(1-p_1)=\frac{7074278599678754816}{278301155710840989377}\approx0.02541951\;.
$$

Thus the correlations increase the probability by about $3\%$.

The code also performs simulations that reproduce the results to five decimal digits. It could easily be adapted to similar computations (e.g. for two-pair hands).